# Html.Grid containing checkbox per row

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I am using Html.Grid in my asp.net MVC2 application.

The grid contains checkboxes per row.

```
<%= Html.Grid<MyViewModel>(Model.MyList)
        .Columns( column => {
            column.For(x => Html.CheckBox("Select", false, new { id = x.ID })).DoNotEncode();
```

I need to loop through the checked records and action them. How can I retrieve the checked id values when I do a postback on a button click.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at a custom ModelBinder.

I am using the grid and I have a checkbox column that looks like this:

```
column.For(x => Html.CheckBox(x.CatalogItemId +  "-rcvd", false)).DoNotEncode().Named("Received");
```

My action signature in the controller to handle post back is this:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(PendingRecievedItemsBinder))]IEnumerable<ShelfMyndr.Models.Previews.PendingReceivedCatalogItem> rcvdCatalogItems)
```

You just need a class that implements `IModelBinder`. In the `BindModel` method you can do something like this:

```
foreach (string key in controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k => controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[k].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length > 1))
        {
            if (key.EndsWith("-rcvd"))
            {
                ci.IsReceived = true;
            }
```

Using this, my controller's action can focus on what do do with a list of items, instead of iterating thru the Forms collection itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working with more or less the same grid code.

The Checkbox column I have defined more or less the same as yours:

```
column.For(x => Html.SimpleCheckBox("keys", x.Id.ToString())).DoNotEncode();
```

The grid is wrapped in a form.

The form posts back to the following method.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Process(IList<int> keys) {
// do stuff with the keys
}
```

If you have "Select" as the checkbox name, then I guess the parameter name would also be Select.

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this

```
x.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(20).RenderValueAs(y => Html.Raw(" 
<input type='checkbox' value='"+y.IsAdmin+"' ) />"));
```

it will add checkbox on each row.